# Compare std::set with custom comparer

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am trying to use the `std::tie` to implement the `operator<` in order to create a map of structs that contain a set. The same code without templates seem that it works. I am getting this message code from my compiler:

> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:888: error: no match for `operator<` (operand types are `const SiPa<int, int>` and `const SiPa<int, int>`)
>
> ```
> if (*__first1 < *__first2)
>               ^
> ```

Everything compiles if I comment the `myMap.insert({akey, true});` line.

Any hints?

```
template<class I = int, class S = int>
struct SiPa
{
    I i;
    S s;
};

template<class I = int, class S = int>
struct SiPaComparator
{
    bool operator() (const SiPa<I, S>& first, const SiPa<I, S>& second) const
    {
        return std::tie(first.i, first.s) < std::tie(second.i, second.s);
    }
};

template<class I = int, class S = int>
struct AKey
{
    typedef std::set< SiPa<I, S>, SiPaComparator<I,S> > SetType;
    SetType keySet;
    I keyI;
};

template<class I = int, class S = int>
struct AKeyComparator
{
    bool operator() (const AKey<I, S>& first, const AKey<I, S>& second) const
    {
        return std::tie(first.keySet, first.keyI) < std::tie(second.keySet, second.keyI);
    }
};

int main()
{
    AKey<int,int> akey;

    std::map<AKey<int,int>, bool, AKeyComparator<int,int>> myMap;
    myMap.insert({akey, true});
}
```

Comment: MCVE can be reduced to [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4de5a0b8e59a6bfb).

Comment: @Jarod42 what do you mean?

Comment: I mean it is not related to `std::tie`, but just compare 2 `std::set` with custom comparer. Looking at [set operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/operators/), `Comparer` is not used :-(

Comment: thank you very much.. this is a strange STL interface then..

Comment: Please correct the question now that we know `std::tie` has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: somebody already did it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need add operator< for struct SiPa, std::map require it

```
template<class I = int, class S = int>
struct SiPa {
  I i;
  S s;

  bool operator<(const SiPa<I, S> &ref) {
    return i < ref.i && s < ref.s;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I am wondering why it is needed if I am passing the comparator function both to the map and the set

Comment: @user3770392 : [`operator <` for `std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp) **always** compares with `std::lexicographical_compare`, not the comparator you supply. To use that, [`std::set::key_comp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/key_comp) is available. @Dawid : `std::set` is what requires the `operator <` here, not `std::map`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 2):

In general, comparators on `map`s and `set`s are *stateful*.  When comparing two different `set`s or `map`s, there is no obvious way to pick which one to use.

So when comparing different `set`s and `map`s via `<`, you get [`std::lexographical_compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) with no `Compare` argument, which uses `<`.  (Note this sucks for `set`s of pointers to objects not from the same array)

```
struct order_by_tie {
  template<class Lhs, class Rhs,
    class=std::enable_if_t<
      std::is_base_of<order_by_tie, Lhs>::value
      && std::is_base_of<order_by_tie, Rhs>::value
    >
  >
  friend bool operator<(Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs) {
    return as_tie(lhs) < as_tie(rhs);
  }
};
```

`order_by_tie` is intended to be inherited from.  It uses ADL (argument dependent lookup) to enable `<` on its descendent classes, implemented by calling the free function `as_tie` on each side then doing a `<`.

We use it as follows:

```
template<class I = int, class S = int>
struct SiPa:order_by_tie
{
  I i;
  S s;
  friend auto as_tie( SiPa const& self ) {
    return std::tie(self.i, self.s);
  }
};

template<class I = int, class S = int>
struct AKey:order_by_tie
{
  typedef std::set< SiPa<I, S>, SiPaComparator<I,S> > SetType;
  SetType keySet;
  I keyI;
  friend auto as_tie( AKey const& self ) {
    return std::tie(self.keySet, self.keyI);
  }
};
```

then

```
std::map<AKey<int,int>, bool> myMap;
```

works.

`as_tie` uses C++14, because the alternative is annoying.  You can add a `-> decltype(std::tie( blah, blah ))` for C++11 (repeating yourself).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, a really interesting alternative

Comment: @user3770392 The `order_by_tie` disappears at runtime (0 size) and the `as_tie` and the like code evaporates with suitable optimization setttings.  I am unaware of any runtime costs.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/operators/

> The other operations also use the operators == and < internally to compare the elements, behaving as if the following equivalent operations were performed:
>
> Notice that **none of these operations take into consideration the internal comparison object of neither container**.

So the comparaison of `std::set<SiPa<I, S>, SiPaComparator<I,S>>` is done with

```
operator < (const SiPa<I, S>&, const SiPa<I, S>&)
```

and not with

```
SiPaComparator<I, S>{}
```

The workaround is to define that `operator <`.

Comment: what I don't understand is then why you can pass the SiPaComparator<I,S> if it is not taken into account..

Comment: if I implement the operator< there's no need to create that comparator at all

Comment: @user3770392: I think the rational is that for `operator ==`, they don't want that `==` means equivalence. Or maybe the problem is which `Comparer` to use (lhs or rhs one).

Comment: @user3770392 : `std::set` uses the comparator you give it in order to maintain its invariants. But when you use `operator <` on a set, it in turn uses `operator <` on its elements; If you don't want it to use `<`, then don't use `<` on it. ;-]